# How can I display two items of Carousel in the frontend by TYPO3?

Tags: html, typo3, carousel, fluid

I want to display two items of carousel side by side in the frontend in TYPO3, but I can display just one item now.

I have no idea how I can write some codes with Fluid in a HTML-file to display two items.
I use a plug-In `bootstrap_package` and bild a carousel like a carousel of `bootstrap_packgae` now. But the carousel of `bootstrap_package` has just a item on a slide.

However, I want to display two items on a page and if a user click a button (preview or next), another item will be displayed. My image is like this:
[image]

Now my codes in a HTM-file `CarouselStartseiteAngebote.html` (in Template) seem like so:

```
<f:if condition="{records}">
  <div id="carousel-{data.uid}" class="carousel carousel-small carousel-startseite-angebote carousel-{data.pi_flexform.transition} slide" {f:if(condition: data.pi_flexform.interval, then: 'data-interval="{data.pi_flexform.interval}" ')}data-wrap="{f:if(condition:data.pi_flexform.wrap,then:'true',else:'false')}" data-ride="carousel" {f:if(condition: data.pi_flexform.interval, then: 'data-bs-interval="{data.pi_flexform.interval}"')} data-bs-wrap="{f:if(condition:data.pi_flexform.wrap,then:'true',else:'false')}" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner carousel-startseite-angebote-inner">
      <f:for each="{records}" as="item" iteration="iteration">
        <f:variable name="itemClass">item</f:variable>
          <f:if condition="{iteration.isFirst}">
             <f:variable name="itemClass">{itemClass} active</f:variable>
          </f:if>
          <f:variable name="itemClass">{itemClass} carousel-item</f:variable>
          <f:variable name="itemClass">{itemClass} carousel-item-layout-{f:if(condition: item.data.layout,then:item.data.layout,else: 'custom')}</f:variable>
          <f:variable name="itemClass">{itemClass} carousel-item-type-{item.data.item_type}</f:variable>
          <div class="{itemClass}" data-itemno="{iteration.index}">
             <f:render partial="Carousel/General/BackgroundImage" arguments="{_all}" />
             <div class="carousel-content carousel-startseite-angebote-content">
               <f:render partial="Carousel/Item/{item.data.item_type -> bk2k:format.upperCamelCase()}" arguments="{_all}" />                                
             </div>
          </div>
       </f:for>
     </div>
     <f:render partial="Carousel/Control/ControlStartseiteAngebote" arguments="{_all}" />
   </div>
</f:if>
```

In a `CarouselStartseiteAngebote.html` (in Partial):

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
<f:if condition="{records -> f:count()} > 1">   
        <button data-slide="prev" data-target="#carousel-{data.uid}" data-bs-slide="prev" data-bs-target="#carousel-{data.uid}" type="button" class="carousel-control carousel-control-prev carousel-startseite-angebote-control-prev">
            <span class="startseite-angebote-icons-prev carousel-startseite-angebote-icons slidenow"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">{f:translate(key: 'previous', extensionName: 'rasanidesign_startseite-angebote')}</span>
        </button>
        <button data-slide="next" data-target="#carousel-{data.uid}" data-bs-slide="next" data-bs-target="#carousel-{data.uid}" type="button" class="carousel-control carousel-control-next carousel-startseite-angebote-control-next">
            <span class="startseite-angebote-icons-next carousel-startseite-angebote-icons"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">{f:translate(key: 'next', extensionName: 'rasanidesign_startseite-angebote')}</span>
        </button>
</f:if>
</html>
```

In a `TextAndImageForCarouselStartseiteAngebote.html` (in Partial):

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
<f:link.typolink parameter="{item.data.link}" additionalAttributes="{draggable:'false'}">
    <div class="carousel-sa-content">
        <!-- Slider1 -->
        <div class="carousel-startseite-angebote-content-inner-container row saslider">
            <!-- Imagefeld -->
            <div class="carousel-startseite-angebote-left col">
                <f:if condition="{item.images.0}">
                    <f:variable name="image-startseite-angeboteConfig">{settings.responsiveimages.contentelements.{data.CType}}</f:variable>
                    <f:variable name="image-startseite-angeboteConfig">{image-startseite-angeboteConfig.{item.data.item_type}}</f:variable>
                    <bk2k:data.imageVariants as="variants" variants="{variants}" multiplier="{image-startseite-angeboteConfig.multiplier}" gutters="{image-startseite-angeboteConfig.gutters}" corrections="{image-startseite-angeboteConfig.corrections}" />
                    <f:render partial="Media/Rendering/ImageStartseiteAngebote" arguments="{file: item.images.0, data: item.data, settings: settings, variants: variants}" />
                </f:if>
            </div>
            <!-- Textfeld -->
            <div class="carousel-startseite-angebote-right col">
                <div class="carousel-startseite-angebote-right-container">
                    <h{item.data.header_layout} class="carousel-startseite-angebote-header-h4 carousel-header{f:if(condition: item.data.header_class, then: ' {item.data.header_class}')}{f:if(condition: item.data.header_position, then: ' text-{item.data.header_position}')}"><f:format.htmlspecialchars doubleEncode="false">{item.data.header}</f:format.htmlspecialchars></h{item.data.header_layout}>
                <f:if condition="{item.data.subheader}">
                    <h{item.data.subheader_layout} class="carousel-startseite-angebote-header-h2 carousel-startseite-angebote-image carousel-subheader{f:if(condition: item.data.subheader_class, then: ' {item.data.subheader_class}')}{f:if(condition: item.data.header_position, then: ' text-{item.data.header_position}')}"><f:format.htmlspecialchars doubleEncode="false">{item.data.subheader}</f:format.htmlspecialchars></h{item.data.subheader_layout}>
                </f:if>
                <span class="carousel-startseite-angebote-bodytext"><f:format.html>{item.data.bodytext}</f:format.html></span>
                </div>                    
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
</f:link.typolink>
</html>
```

What schould I wirte codes to display two items side by side? The items have to switch step by step and they have to be repeated.

I tryed to give a condition on the line 6 in the `CarouselStartseiteAngebote.html`:

```
<f:if condition="{iteration.isFirst} && {iteration.index}">
```

If I check it using developer-tool, then I could find two items. But I can't display anything in the frontend, even first item, because the word "active" is disappeared.:
[image]

How can I add the word "active" for the two items? ALso, if another item comes up, how can I remove the word "active" from the previous item?

I hope someone can give me an advice or correct codes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That't actually more a styling thing. Take a slider plugin that fit your needs e.g. https://swiperjs.com/demos#slides-per-view
and build the template (html, css, js) according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is it possble in TYPO3 too? I use Fluid to display my contents in the frontend. I try to use flexbox in a CSS-file. But there are still some problems because of class name. Fluid generates a class name for each items and they have same class name e.g. `carousel-item-type-text_and_image_for_carousel_startseite_angebote`. Please check it on the above picture by developer-tool. That's why I can still display just one item...

Comment: First you need a plain HTML-CSS-JS solution that works. Then you take over the HTML in you Fluid-Template and replace some parts with Fluid-Tags to fill in data and make things dynamic. Include your css and js (TypoScript or Fluid) and then it will work - again: nothing really related to TYPO3 here.

Answer (score 0):

In general:
Special interactive elements in a web page are build normally by javascript that takes some standard HTML like lists and transforms it to a carousel, an accordion, a slider or similar.

This javascript needs a container which is identified by a class or an id so that the controls only effect the contained elements of this element.

In this way you can have two carousels (or similar) in a page which are independent of each other.

In TYPO3 you have full control over the rendering and can generate everything you like by adding your own fluid templates. for the unique identifier you can use the `uid` field of the content element or any relevant record.

You can display anything as far as you have the javascript library to modify the original HTML and to change the HTML for your wished behaviour.
Look in the web to get a javascript library which handles your behaviour, include it in the page, build the required HTML markup and don't forget to add the initialization call for each element (that could either behind the HTML) or with an asset viewhelper in the usual position at the end of the page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Okay, I thought I need to modify just Fluid. I'll try to modify my HTML-files and find some JavaScript out. Thank you.

Comment: Fluid-Files = HTML-Files. Fluid "just" gives you special HTML-Tags (View Helper) to do more dynamic stuff and help you display field information from the system.